# svn error with Apache internal server error

Tags: apache, svn

I tried to install svn server in local

I entered this configuration in my server's /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf

```
Alias /svn /var/www/svn
 <Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/www/svn/
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion repositories"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
  Require valid-user
 </Location>
```

And restarted httpd.service

I'm getting this error message when i go to this url http://localhost/svn/repo

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved a similar issue of my own. What I used for debugging was the following:

- Check the error log file at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`
- Try without the `Require valid-user`, this is probably not what you want, but if it works without it's probably an issue with the authentication modules.
- Verify if you created a password file `htpasswd -c -m /etc/svn-auth-users aymen`
- Verify if the authentication modules are turned on: `sudo a2enmod auth_basic`

BTW, I recommend using auth_digest instead, auth_basic sends you password almost as plain text over the network, so it's vulnerable to sniffing attacks. You can check my question+answer for more information:
[Apache webserver Require valid-user leads to internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164198/apache-webserver-require-valid-user-leads-to-internal-server-error/46173064#46173064)

Comment: Don't use answers for comments. If you don't have the privilege of commenting yet, there's a good reason for that. However, in this case, it wasn't really a comment.