# Apache webserver Require valid-user leads to internal server error

Tags: apache, svn

I'm setting up an SVN server and want to restrict access so all users have to log in first before they can view/modify files. My dav_svn.conf looks like this:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /home/pi/repos
  # Authentication: Digest
  AuthName "Subversion repository"
  AuthType Digest
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn-auth.htdigest
  # Authorization: Authenticated users only
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

When I try to access the webpage it shows "Internal Server Error". Looking inside the "/var/log/apache2/error.log" shows the following line:

> [Mon Sep 11 20:36:47.755229 2017] [authn_core:error] [pid 30331:tid
>   1972368432] [client 192.168.0.103:59263] AH01796: AuthType Digest
>   configured without corresponding module, referer:
>   http://192.168.0.100/svn/A/

I can "fix" the error by changing the dav_svn.conf by putting an extra XML tag around "Require valid-user":

```
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
  Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

However, with this I obviously open viewing rights to everyone and their mother. I can also verify this by trying to access the webpage and I do indeed get in without a password. When trying to POST I get the same error again.

I've tried to search for the error online a lot, but other than countless examples who give exactly this  example, nobody seems to have a problem with it... Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it turned out this specific part of the authentication functionality is not enabled by default. Something the examples I found online failed to mention. I did the following:

> sudo a2enmod auth_digest

which gave this output:

```
Considering dependency authn_core for auth_digest:
Module authn_core already enabled
Enabling module auth_digest.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
service apache2 restart
```

So the authn_core was already enabled, but not the digest. This is odd as it was already possible to create a digest password file:

> sudo htdigest -c /etc/apache2/svn-auth.htdigest realm "Subversion repository"